# Magento Captcha in contact form on CMS page

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9, captcha, contact-form

I want to include the magento standard captcha in my contact form into a cms-page.

The form will be included  in the cms-content-field of the page.

```
{{block type="core/template" name="contactForm" form_action="/contacts/index/post" template="contacts/form.phtml"}}
```

This works great. No Problems.

There are many tutorials for including the standard-captcha into the standard contact form. 
https://janakbhimani.wordpress.com/2013/09/14/how-to-add-captcha-in-contact-us-form-in-magento-1-7-0-2/
http://www.phpfunctionoftheday.com/magento-captcha-contact-form/

But the captcha will not shown in my form.

Apparently these solutions do work on the normal contact form (contacts/index/index), but this seems to be the wrong path for my contact form.

I tested it with some other paths like core/template, but I can´t find the right way.

Now I'm searching for a solution where the captcha will work on my contact form.
Does anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 0):

If you follow above links and create modules and "Contact us" option in captcha section in admin side then add following code in Design tab in your cms page.

```
<reference name="content">
            <block type="captcha/captcha" name="captcha">
                <reference name="head">
                    <action method="addJs"><file>mage/captcha.js</file></action>
                </reference>
                <action method="setFormId"><formId>contact_page_captcha</formId></action>
                <action method="setImgWidth"><width>230</width></action>
                <action method="setImgHeight"><width>50</width></action>
            </block>
</reference>
```

let me know if you still face the issue.

Answer (score -1):

Use below captcha extension :

https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/contacts-form-captcha.html